# nw js - inconsistent transparency in Windows

Tags: windows, transparency, nwjs

We are using nwjs to develop cross platform application. Application has a main window that is transparent. When we create this window for the first time, it has transparency. This window gets closed and opened during the course of application flow. When this window is reopened again (application is still running), transparency is lost and window appears with White background. This behaviour is intermittent (once in 10 times) and happens only on Windows 7/8/10

Comment: Are you using any scripts to change transparency for *any* of the tags that cover the space that turns white?

Comment: No. We are simply setting the transparent attribute to true. nw.Window.open('...', {
"frame": false,
"transparent": true,
"width": 660,
"height": 550,
"show_in_taskbar": false,
"show": false
});